# How to **change** the vscode settings sync service from Insiders back to Stable?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I started using VSCode Insiders and wanted to sync my Stable version extensions to Insider. According to [the official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync#_syncing-stable-versus-insiders), I need to select "Stable" as the sync service. However I didn't notice this the first time I started Settings Sync and chose "Insiders". I cannot find how to change this to "Stable" in Settings/VSCode Command Palette; logout and re-login doesn't work; reinstalling VSCode Insiders doesn't work.

How can I change the service to Stable?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Encountered the problem myself and figured out a way to solve it.

1. First you click on an account icon and select "Setting sync is On"
2. Select "Settings Sync: Turn Off" -> Confirm logging out and deleting sync data
3. Find account icon again and click "Turn on Settings sync". Choose what to sync and hoopla! Get a prompt to choose Sync service.